# Parse detect ParseClient is not initialized

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com in my app. I see that sometimes if Parse.ParseClient.Initialize() method fails, ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens still run and eventually crash my app.

So how can I detect if ParseClient failed to initialize?

In App constructor:

```
this.Startup += async (sender, args) =>
        {
              //crash if ParseClient is not initialized
              //Parse.ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make a Test Call to your Parse DB and wrap it around with `try` `catch` block before you use the `ParseAnalytics`.

Something like..

```
ParseClient.Initialize();

try
{
    client.GetObject("SomeTestORDummyObject");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Indicates that Initialize failed..
}

ParseAnalytics.TrackAppOpens(RootFrame);
```

Comment: Thanks. So sad that there is no API :(